# How to get list of modified files of a Git repo in python?

Tags: python, git

I am trying to write a function using python to determine modified files in a git repository. I saw there are couple of packages:

- [`Gittle`](https://pypi.org/project/gittle/#description)
- [`git-python`](https://pypi.org/project/git-python/)
- [`GitPython`](https://pypi.org/project/GitPython/)

How can I get a list of `pathlib.Path` instances of **modified files**?

Python version in use: 3.8

## Edit:

In order to check modified files in GitPython I have tried the following:

```
diff = repo.git.diff('HEAD~1..HEAD', name_only=True)
```

but this gives me the files that are different, comparing the latest commit with the one before, instead of comparing the latest commit with unstaged changes.

Comment: Just going on GH stars, I'd say GitPython. Definitely not git-python which seems to have no users. GitPython is usually the one I hear people discussing on podcasts etc. too.

Comment: Try `diff = repo.git.diff(name_only=True)`.

Comment: Seems to be it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a definitive list of what's changed (but not yet staged):

```
# Gives a list of the differing objects
diff_list = repo.head.commit.diff()

for diff in diff_list:
    print(diff.change_type) # Gives the change type. eg. 'A': added, 'M': modified etc.

    # Returns true if it is a new file
    print(diff.new_file) 

    # Print the old file path
    print(diff.a_path)

    # Print the new file path. If the filename (or path) was changed it will differ
    print(diff.b_path) 

# Too many options to show. This gives a comprehensive description of what is available
help(diff_list[0])
```

I found the diff object to be very useful and should give any info you require.

For staged items, use `repo.index`

The other option is `repo.git.diff(...)` which I found less useful as it gives long text strings for output rather than objects that can be easily parsed.